# Record Video for Specific Layout in android

Tags: android, video-capture, android-video-record

How can i record video in android for a specific layout in an activity?
I have an activity which has a linearlayout and that contains textview with some animations and i want to record video of the animations played so is there any way possible in android?

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvLabel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Animation will be in this textview"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:background="@color/color_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btnPlayAnim"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Play Animation" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btnStopAnim"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Stop Animation" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btnMakeVideo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Start Recording" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use the media projection APIs to record the screen. Then, crop the resulting video to your desired coordinates.

Comment: Hey @Parth have you got the solution for this ? i'm also looking for same.